# Clicking on link in dask dashboard doesn't work ("unable to connect")

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have installed the dask extension utility for my jupyter lab sessions following the instructions [here](https://github.com/dask/dask-labextension). The installation, on my university linux cluster, went through smoothly.

When I launch a client in the Jupyter notebook, the dashboard shows a link: http://127.0.0.1:8787/status. Clicking on the link should open up the dask diagnostics in a separate tab. That link, however, does not work for me and gives an "unable to connect" message. I checked with an administrator managing the cluster that port 8787 (in the link) is indeed open to regular users like myself. So, something else seems to be the problem.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you forwarding the port 8787 to localhost on the machine you are working on, e.g. using an ssh session if you are on linux, or puTTy on windows?

Comment: I tried port forwarding using `ssh -L 8080:<remoteserver>:8787...`, I still get the "unable to connect" message when I click the link in the dask dashboard.  Does it matter that I am using vpn to connect to the server?

Comment: I would guess clicking the link takes you to port 8787, but locally the correct port is 8080 according to your comment. Have you managed to connect to other services, e.g. a jupyter notebook, through an ssh tunnel from this server before?